# How can I create an apt repository mirror on a network that is isolated from the internet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, packages, apt

I have a network that has no internet connectivity from any of the devices. The only way I can get data on it from the outside world is via a USB mass storage device (USB stick, external hard drive, external CD/DVD drive).

These devices are all running Ubuntu. Because of the offline nature of the network, I am unable to easily install new software using `apt` as I would if I were on an internet-connected machine. However, installing software via `apt` is something I would like to do.

What is the simplest way for me to be able to go onto one of the devices on my network and type `apt install [package]` in order to install `[package]`?

Comment: Do you want to just install a handful of packages from a USB?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a local repository and pointing `apt` to it. You can create a USB Drive that serves as a offline source of packages.

Here is the page in the community documentation wiki on how you can do it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository.

Comment: Thanks. I have taken a read through that page. The way I am interpreting it: Re-create the structure of http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists for the architecture and release I am using on the USB drive (Or locally on one of the nodes). However, there are 2 things confusing me from here: when/how do we actually download the packages? And how do we point apt to the new repo if we don't have a GUI?